# Why am I getting "parameter is never used [E0392]"?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement an Octree in Rust. The Octree is generic over a type with a constraint that it should implement a generic trait:

```
pub trait Generable<U> {
    fn generate_children(&self, data: &U) -> Vec<Option<Self>>;
}

pub enum Octree<T, U>
where
    T: Generable<U>,
{
    Node {
        data: T,
        children: Vec<Box<Octree<T, U>>>,
    },
    Empty,
    Uninitialized,
}
```

Here is a [simplified example reproducing the issue on the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1dc357caf8bd488da4ae9ed169324c30&version=stable)

This generates an error:

```
error[E0392]: parameter `U` is never used
 --> src/main.rs:5:20
  |
5 | pub enum Octree<T, U>
  |                    ^ unused type parameter
  |
  = help: consider removing `U` or using a marker such as `std::marker::PhantomData`
```

Removing the `U` from the signature results in "undeclared type name 'U'".

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug? How to do this properly?

Comment: Looks like a limitation of the compiler, you can probably work around it by playing around with [PhantomData](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html#unused-type-parameters), adding a "fake" member `PhantomData<*const U>`, while you wait for a more definitive answer.

Comment: That helped, thanks. Although it would be nice to be able to use those structures without PhantomData ;)

Comment: You're welcome :) I'd really like to know if your code is supposed to be rejected or if it's a compiler bug...

Comment: I've found an issue on Github that looks similar (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26283) and someone there seems to think that it's a limitation of the compiler, but I'm not sure if that's really the same...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't believe you want another generic here, [you want an *associated type*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32059370/155423):

```
pub trait Generable {
    type From;
    fn generate_children(&self, data: &Self::From) -> Vec<Option<Self>>
    where
        Self: Sized;
}

pub enum Octree<T>
where
    T: Generable,
{
    Node {
        data: T,
        children: Vec<Box<Octree<T>>>,
    },
    Empty,
    Uninitialized,
}

fn main() {}
```

As an aside, `Vec<Box<Octree<T>>>` is probably one level extra of indirection — you can just use `Vec<Octree<T>>`.

Comment: as of 1.31.1, we need to add `Sized`  bound on `Self`; `pub trait Generable where Self:Sized { ...`