# When is it appropriate to use an associated type versus a generic type?

Tags: types, rust, idioms

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32053402/155423), an issue arose that could be solved by changing an attempt at using a generic type parameter into an associated type. That prompted the question "Why is an associated type more appropriate here?", which made me want to know more.

The [RFC that introduced associated types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0195-associated-items.md) says:

> This RFC clarifies trait matching by:
>
> - Treating all trait type parameters as *input types*, and
> - Providing associated types, which are *output types*.

The RFC uses a graph structure as a motivating example, and this is also used in [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#specifying-placeholder-types-in-trait-definitions-with-associated-types), but I'll admit to not fully appreciating the benefits of the associated type version over the type-parameterized version. The primary thing is that the `distance` method doesn't need to care about the `Edge` type. This is nice but seems a bit shallow of a reason for having associated types at all.

I've found associated types to be pretty intuitive to use in practice, but I find myself struggling when deciding where and when I should use them in my own API.

When writing code, when should I choose an associated type over a generic type parameter, and when should I do the opposite?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

This is now touched on in [the second edition of *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#specifying-placeholder-types-in-trait-definitions-with-associated-types). However, let's dive in a bit in addition.

Let us start with a simpler example.

> When is it appropriate to use a trait method?

There are multiple ways to provide *late binding*:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn hello_world(&self) -> String;
}
```

Or:

```
struct MyTrait<T> {
    t: T,
    hello_world: fn(&T) -> String,
}

impl<T> MyTrait<T> {
    fn new(t: T, hello_world: fn(&T) -> String) -> MyTrait<T>;

    fn hello_world(&self) -> String {
        (self.hello_world)(self.t)
    }
}
```

Disregarding any implementation/performance strategy, both excerpts above allow the user to specify in a dynamic manner how `hello_world` should behave.

The one difference (semantically) is that the `trait` implementation guarantees that for a given type `T` implementing the `trait`, `hello_world` will always have the same behavior whereas the `struct` implementation allows having a different behavior on a per instance basis.

Whether using a method is appropriate or not depends on the usecase!

> When is it appropriate to use an associated type?

Similarly to the `trait` methods above, an associated type is a form of late binding (though it occurs at compilation), allowing the user of the `trait` to specify for a given instance which type to substitute. It is not the only way (thus the question):

```
trait MyTrait {
    type Return;
    fn hello_world(&self) -> Self::Return;
}
```

Or:

```
trait MyTrait<Return> {
    fn hello_world(&Self) -> Return;
}
```

Are equivalent to the late binding of methods above:

- the first one enforces that for a given `Self` there is a single `Return` associated
- the second one, instead, allows implementing `MyTrait` for `Self` for multiple `Return`

Which form is more appropriate depends on whether it makes sense to enforce unicity or not. For example:

- `Deref` uses an associated type because without unicity the compiler would go mad during inference
- `Add` uses an associated type because its author thought that given the two arguments there would be a logical return type

As you can see, while `Deref` is an obvious usecase (technical constraint), the case of `Add` is less clear cut: maybe it would make sense for `i32 + i32` to yield either `i32` or `Complex<i32>` depending on the context? Nonetheless, the author exercised their judgment and decided that overloading the return type for additions was unnecessary.

My personal stance is that there is no right answer. Still, beyond the unicity argument, I would mention that associated types make using the trait easier as they decrease the number of parameters that have to be specified, so in case the benefits of the flexibility of using a regular trait parameter are not obvious, I suggest starting with an associated type.

Comment: Let me try to simplify a bit:

`trait/struct MyTrait/MyStruct` allows exactly one `impl MyTrait for` or `impl MyStruct`.

`trait MyTrait<Return>` allows multiple `impl`s because it's generic. `Return` can be any type. Generic structs are the same.

Comment: I find your answer much easier to understand than the one in "The Rust Programming Language"

Comment: "the first one enforces that for a given Self there is a single Return associated". This is true in the immediate sense, but one could of course work round this restriction by subclassing with a generic trait. Perhaps unicity can only be a suggestion, and not enforced

Answer (score 59):

Associated types are a *grouping mechanism*, so they should be used when it makes sense to group types together.

The `Graph` trait introduced in the documentation is an example of this. You want a `Graph` to be generic, but once you have a specific kind of `Graph`, you don't want the `Node` or `Edge` types to vary anymore. A particular `Graph` isn't going to want to vary those types within a single implementation, and in fact, wants them to always be the same. They're grouped together, or one might even say *associated*.

Comment: It took me some time to understand. To me it looks more like defining several types at once: the Edge and the Node don't make sense out of the graph.

Comment: I still don't get it, can you go into more detail?

Comment: what about all the iterators in the standard library, is the logic same as here?

Answer (score 1):

Associated types can be used to tell the compiler "these two types between these two implementations are the same". Here's a double dispatch example that compiles, and is almost similar to how the standard library relates iterator to sum types:

```
trait MySum {
    type Item;
    fn sum<I>(iter: I)
    where
        I: MyIter<Item = Self::Item>;
}

trait MyIter {
    type Item;
    fn next(&self) {}
    fn sum<S>(self)
    where
        S: MySum<Item = Self::Item>;
}

struct MyU32;

impl MySum for MyU32 {
    type Item = MyU32;

    fn sum<I>(iter: I)
    where
        I: MyIter<Item = Self::Item>,
    {
        iter.next()
    }
}

struct MyVec;

impl MyIter for MyVec {
    type Item = MyU32;
    fn sum<S>(self)
    where
        S: MySum<Item = Self::Item>,
    {
        S::sum::<Self>(self)
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Also, https://blog.thomasheartman.com/posts/on-generics-and-associated-types has some good information on this as well:

> In short, use generics when you want to type `A` to be able to implement a trait any number of times for different type parameters, such as in the case of the From trait.

> Use associated types if it makes sense for a type to only implement the trait once, such as with Iterator and Deref.