# What does `type Item` in the `Iterator` trait mean

Tags: rust

The `Iterator` trait is defined as follows:

```
pub trait Iterator {
    type Item;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>;
}
```

What does `type Item;` mean? And how to call it?

Is the definition above equivalent to this one?

```
pub trait Iterator<T> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T>;
}
```

If it's the same why declare it that way? And if it's not the same then what's the difference?

Comment: *And if it's not the same then what's the difference?* — [When is it appropriate to use an associated type versus a generic type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059370/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-an-associated-type-versus-a-generic-type)

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**: The `type Item;` in `Iterator` is an *associated* type.

---

Rust generics have both Input and Output types:

- Input types are those specified in the declaration of the trait (`trait X<T, U>` has `T` and `U` as input types) plus `Self` (the concrete type for which the trait is being implemented)
- Output types are those specified in the definition of the trait via `type X;`

The RFC that introduced associated items is [RFC 195: Associated Items](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0195-associated-items.md). Specifically, its [motivation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0195-associated-items.md#motivation) section cites the benefits of having associated traits.

For me, the most important point is **unicity**: a single type is defined for any given implementation of the trait, which allows cleanly powering the `Deref` or `Index` trait for example. In a world where `Deref` or `Index` could yield many possible types, type inference would be even more complicated.