# Bounded trait parameter with supertrait in Rust

Tags: haskell, generics, rust, typeclass, traits

I am new to both Haskell and Rust and am attempting to translate Haskell code into Rust so as to compare the features that support genericity. However, it seems I either need help with syntax or some fundamental concepts in Rust.

I have this code in Haskell:

```hs
class HasEmpty a where
    empty :: a
    isEmpty :: a -> Bool

class Hashable a where
    hash :: a -> Int

class (HasEmpty x, Hashable (Element x))
        => Hashset x where
    type Element x
    size :: x -> Int
```

The important part is at the bottom where we define a type class named `Hashset` which takes a single parameter `x` and sub-classes `HasEmpty`. The body of the type class defines an associated type, which is required to be `Hashable`, and an associated method `size`.

How can I do the same thing in Rust? Here is what I've written thus far:

```
trait HasEmpty {
    fn empty(&self);
    fn is_empty(&self) -> bool;
}

trait Hashable {
    fn hash(&self) -> u32;
}

trait Hashset<E>
    where E: Hashable
{
    fn size(&self) -> i32;
}
```

This compiles and allows me to say that the associated type `E` is   Hashable, but how can I 'inherit' the 'trait methods' of `HasEmpty` by using it as a supertrait? I know this is possible by saying:

```
trait Hashset: HasEmpty {
    fn size(&self) -> i32;
}
```

but is it possible to both constrain the associated type and use a supertrait? Perhaps I am asking the wrong question.

Comment: [One question per question, please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829).

Comment: Your Rust definition of `empty` is more like `a -> ()` in Haskell. Better would be `fn empty() -> Self;` .

Comment: I have a feeling you're using Haskell's classes inappropriately. Type classes are not like OO classes; they're more like interfaces. Unless you have a requirement to abstract over various different implementations of `Hashset` I'd just define a plain old type: `data Hashset a = ...`

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to both constrain the associated type and use a supertrait?

Sure, I'm not sure why you didn't just combine the two syntaxes:

```
trait Hashset<E>: HasEmpty
    where E: Hashable
{
    fn size(&self) -> i32;
}
```

However, you should know that `E` is **not** an associated type, it's just a generic type. See [When is it appropriate to use an associated type versus a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32059370/155423) for more info.

An associated type would be:

```
trait Hashset: HasEmpty {
    type E: Hashable;
    fn size(&self) -> i32;
}
```