# Simple organization of Rust traits for "polymorphic" return

Tags: polymorphism, rust, traits

I have a basic struct called `Frame` that is useful for a bunch of calculations:.

```
pub struct Frame<T> {
    grid_val: Vec<T>,
    grid_space: Vec<[T; 2]>,
    calculated_result: Option<Vec<T>>
}
```

`Frame` can be used to describe most basic calculations, but sometimes there's more complicated issues that come up and I need to add some more geometric information. So I used composition for each geometry:

```
pub struct Sphere<T> {
    grid: Frame<T>,
    radius: T
}

pub struct Hyperbola<T> {
    top_grid: Frame<T>,
    bottom_grid: Frame<T>,
    internal_angle: T
}
```

Now I have a working implementation of `Algorithm` for `Sphere`:

```
pub trait Algorithm<T> {
    fn calculate_something(&self) -> Result<Sphere<T>, Error>
}

impl Algorithm<T> for Hyperbola {
    // do things with top_grid, bottom_grid, and internal_angle
}

impl Algorithm<T> for Sphere {
    // do things with grid and radius
}
```

This fills in `calculated_result` and returns a new `Sphere`. It's implemented this way because `Algorithm` needs to use the extra geometric information to compute the `calculated_result` — semantically, it makes more sense for it to be an implementation on the geometry, whose result happens to be associated with one or more `Frame`s.

I want to implement the same `Algorithm` for `Hyperbola`. In fact, it's very close to the same, and it makes sense for the trait to be the same, but it doesn't make sense for it to return a `Sphere<T>`.

I know that I could add another trait like `GeometricObject` and add another layer of composition, but that seems excessive. I guess I could maybe use a `Box`, but that seems clumsy.

I also thought of having `calculate_something` return a `Vec<T>` to be inserted manually into whichever struct is in use, but then the ergonomics of returning the same struct type the method is called on are ruined (which is a waste in a public impl/trait).

How can I get this organized without making it traits all the way down?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears you want an *associated type*:

```
pub trait Algorithm<T> {
    type Output;

    fn calculate_something(&self) -> Result<Self::Output, Error>;
}

impl<T> Algorithm<T> for Sphere<T> {
    type Output = Sphere<T>;

    fn calculate_something(&self) -> Result<Self::Output, Error> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

impl<T> Algorithm<T> for Hyperbola<T> {
    type Output = Hyperbola<T>;

    fn calculate_something(&self) -> Result<Self::Output, Error> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Associated types [are described in detail](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#specifying-placeholder-types-in-trait-definitions-with-associated-types) in [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/). I **highly recommend** reading through the entire book to become acquainted with what types of features Rust has to offer.

An alternate solution is to define another generic type on the trait:

```
pub trait Algorithm<T, Out = Self> {
    fn calculate_something(&self) -> Result<Out, Error>;
}

impl<T> Algorithm<T> for Sphere<T> {
    fn calculate_something(&self) -> Result<Sphere<T>, Error> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

impl<T> Algorithm<T> for Hyperbola<T> {
    fn calculate_something(&self) -> Result<Hyperbola<T>, Error> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

You then need to decide [When is it appropriate to use an associated type versus a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32059370/155423)

Comment: That's exciting! I didn't really understand that part of the book because I wasn't ready for it, but now I have some good context.