# Rust return known type for generic trait

Tags: generics, casting, rust, traits

I am quite new to Rust and I struggle with generic types:

I have a trait wich I want to implement for multiple types.
The trait contains a function with an unkown return type.

Like this:

```rust
trait A<T> {
    fn info(&self) -> T;
}
```

I want to implement the trait for two structs, the return type should be specified inside those structs.

Like this:

```rust
struct S1 {
    id: i32,
}
struct S2 {
    id: String,
}

impl A for S1 {
    fn info(&self) -> i32 {
        self.id
    }
}

impl A for S2 {
    fn info(&self) -> String {
        self.id
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of combinations for the return type but I don't find one, which is accepted by the compiler. Is this possible at all in Rust or do I have to use some kind of workaround?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think this might be a duplicate of [Simple organization of Rust traits for "polymorphic" return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352088/simple-organization-of-rust-traits-for-polymorphic-return). If you disagree, you may [edit] your question to add more detail.

Comment: [Here is how I would use associated types to solve your problem](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e6dcbd9c3652860b5a6f0b836da307f4). Another question that might help is [When is it appropriate to use an associated type versus a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059370/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-an-associated-type-versus-a-generic-type)