# Can I implement the same trait multiple times in different ways for a single struct?

Tags: serialization, struct, rust

I'd like to serialize a struct in two different ways depending of the situation but I'm facing a problem: with my current knowledge I can only serialize the struct in one way.

Here is my code with `#[derive(Serialize)]` (auto derive)

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct TransactionContent {
    sender_addr: Vec<u8>,
    sender_pubkey: Vec<u8>,
    receiver_addr: Vec<u8>,
    amount: u32,
    timestamp: i64
}
```

I'm using [`bincode::serialize`](https://docs.rs/bincode/1.0.0-alpha7/bincode/fn.serialize.html) to serialize my struct and make it a `Vec<u8>` and I **also** want to store that struct in a JSON file. When serializing to JSON, I'd like to serialize it in my own way, like returning a base58 string for the `Vec<u8>` fields.

This is my own implementation:

```
impl Serialize for TransactionContent {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
        where S: Serializer
    {
        let mut state = serializer.serialize_struct("TransactionContent", 5)?;
        state.serialize_field("sender_addr", &self.sender_addr.to_base58())?;
        state.serialize_field("sender_pubkey", &self.sender_pubkey.to_base58())?;
        state.serialize_field("receiver_addr", &self.receiver_addr.to_base58())?;
        state.serialize_field("amount", &self.amount)?;
        state.serialize_field("timestamp", &self.timestamp)?;
        state.end()
    }
}
```

I can't use the above code simultaneously. If I use the auto derive, the second `Impl` isn't possible. If I use the second one, the `bincode::serialize` function will work but not as I want it to (I want to use `Vec<u8>` for it)

Is there a way that I could use both `Impl` at the same time? Something like a conditional `Impl` for example?

Comment: You can implement different serialization for wrapper `struct TransactionContentBase58(TransactionContent);`. Will it solve your problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot implement the same trait multiple times in multiple ways for a single type.

As [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167642/implementing-multiple-traits-at-the-same-time-for-a-struct#comment79299794_46167642), you can create a *newtype* that wraps the full data and implement the required traits on that:

```rust
use serde::{ser::SerializeStruct, Serialize, Serializer}; // 1.0.117
use serde_json; // 1.0.59

#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
struct Real {
    data: Vec<u8>,
}

struct AsJson<'a>(&'a Real);

impl<'a> Serialize for AsJson<'a> {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let mut state = serializer.serialize_struct("Thing", 1)?;
        state.serialize_field("data", b"this is some data")?;
        state.end()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let r = Real {
        data: vec![1, 2, 3, 4],
    };
    println!("{:?}", serde_json::to_string(&r));
    println!("{:?}", serde_json::to_string(&AsJson(&r)));
}
```

## If you control the trait

You could add a generic parameter to the trait and implement it multiple times for the same type:

```rust
trait Example<T> {}

struct Style1;
struct Style2;

impl Example<Style1> for i32 {}
impl Example<Style2> for i32 {}
```

This isn't without downsides though.

See also:

- [When is it appropriate to use an associated type versus a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32059370/155423)

Comment: I see. Elegant! Thank you for your answer.