# How to omit top-level type parameter in generic / nested structs?

Tags: rust

I want to create a database structure that I can use like this:

```
let c: Database<Disk<u8>> = ...
```

However, when I naively implement it:

```
trait Element {}

trait Storage<E> where E: Element {}

struct Disk<E> where E: Element {
    data: E,
}  

impl<E> Storage<E> for Disk<E> where E: Element {}

struct Database<S>
where
    S: Storage<E>, 
    E: Element,
{
    storage: S,
}
```

I get an error that `E` is unknown:

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `E` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:30:16
   |
30 |     S: Storage<E>, // <-- Error: E not found.
   |                ^ did you mean `Eq`?
```

[Playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=d857a644f486f9da3eac57f87ec15c6e&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

I could obviously make `E` explicit such as:

```
struct DatabaseUgly<S, E>
where
    S: Storage<E>,
    E: Element
```

But then I would have to repeat the element type:

```
let c: DatabaseUgly<Disk<u8>, u8> = ...
```

How can I make `Database` work?

---

Note: Since it happened more than once, please *do not edit the title* of my question without discussing it first. I might not be using the right terminology, but if I knew what exactly to look for I would probably not be asking / searching this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to use associated type in the trait, rather than a generic:

```
trait Element {}

trait Storage { // not generic
    type Element: Element;
}

struct Disk<E>
where
    E: Element,
{
    data: E,
}

impl<E> Storage for Disk<E>
where
    E: Element,
{
    type Element = E;
}

struct Database<S>
where
    S: Storage,
    S::Element: Element,
{
    storage: S,
}
```

([link to playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=cd0d9b1ce46a63e82a1f0dd7dd91d664&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

See also [When is it appropriate to use an associated type versus a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059370/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-an-associated-type-versus-a-generic-type)