# HRTB: Concrete type bounded by a trait containing lifetime type parameter vs bounded by only a lifetime type parameter

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

This is actually an [offshoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54791718/whats-the-difference-between-a-traits-generic-type-and-a-generic-associated-ty#comment105546315_54803174) of this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54791718/whats-the-difference-between-a-traits-generic-type-and-a-generic-associated-ty) question.

Consider the following code:

```
trait Trait<'b> {
    fn func(&'b self) {}
}

struct Struct {}

impl<'s> Trait<'s> for Struct {}

fn test<'s, T:'s>(t: T)
where
    T: Trait<'s>,
{
    t.func();
}
```

It fails, as the compiler sees that `t` lives for less than the `'s` and `'s` is set by the caller (i.e longer than the stack-frame of the `func`) and traits are invariant over type parameters. However, if I introduce HRTB (Higher Rank Trait Bounds) here, the code compiles:

```
fn test<T>(t: T)
where
    T: for<'s> Trait<'s>,
{
    t.func();
}
```

Now, the trait `Trait<'s>` is implemented for all possible lifetimes `'s` represents and accordingly the right one gets picked by the compiler.

But then why the following code fails ?

```
struct Temp<'a> {
    x: &'a i32,
}

fn test<T>(t: T)
where
    for<'s> T: 's,
{
}

fn main() {
    let d = 1i32;
    test(Temp { x: &d });
}
```

It gives the error:

```
error[E0597]: `d` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:13:20
   |
13 |     test(Temp { x: &d });
   |     ---------------^^---
   |     |              |
   |     |              borrowed value does not live long enough
   |     argument requires that `d` is borrowed for `'static`
14 | }
   | - `d` dropped here while still borrowed
```

What is the difference here? Conceptually, I found the earlier example same as this one. Why it is expected that the concrete type `T` should only be/contain reference(s) with `'static` lifetime(s) ?

Comment: My intuition here is that the flipping of the hrtb expression to lead with `for` now denotes that the lifetime of T must satisfy all possible lifetimes -- effectively meaning it must be static, and therefore d must have static lifetime too. It shouldn't be necessary to use hrtb here though, right?

Comment: Yes, that's something that came from just playing around with the linked question.