# Using generics with trait

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to implement a trait that contains a generic function. However, I cannot instantiate a struct inside the implemented function.

```rust
trait Extractor {
    fn parse(&self) -> String;
}

struct BooksExtractor {}

impl Extractor for BooksExtractor {
    fn parse(&self) -> String {
        "test".to_owned()
    }
}

struct Pass<E: Extractor> {
    pub extractor: Option<E>,
    pub name: String,
    pub next_pass: Option<Box<Pass<E>>>,
}

trait Robot: Sized {
    fn get_pass<E: Extractor>(&self) -> Pass<E>;
}

struct GutenbergRobot {}

impl Robot for GutenbergRobot {
    fn get_pass<E: Extractor + ?Sized>(&self) -> Pass<E>
        where E: Extractor + Sized {
        Pass {
            extractor: Some(BooksExtractor {}),
            name: "test".to_owned(),
            next_pass: None
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about the parameter expected to be a type for the `extractor` field when trying to instantiate a `Pass` struct inside the implemented function:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:33:29
   |
33 |             extractor: Some(BooksExtractor {}),
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `BooksExtractor`
   |
   = note: expected type `E`
              found type `BooksExtractor`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Robot::get_pass` function should not be generic. Instead you should use an associated type:

```rust
trait Robot: Sized {
    type Extractor: Extractor;
    fn get_pass(&self) -> Pass<Self::Extractor>;
}

impl Robot for GutenbergRobot {
    type Extractor = BooksExtractor;
    fn get_pass(&self) -> Pass<BooksExtractor> {
        Pass {
            extractor: Some(BooksExtractor {}),
            name: "test".to_owned(),
            next_pass: None
        }
    }
}
```

In short, you should use a generic when the **caller** can choose the type returned by the function, and an associated type when the **implementer** chooses the type.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32059370/5397009).

Comment: Nice summary, very clear!

Comment: Just a small note: I would change the return type of get_pass in the impl to `-> Pass<Self::Extractor>`. Makes copy-pasting easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your function signature for `get_pass` specifies that it will construct a `Pass<E>` type. That means it should work everywhere where `Pass<E: Extractor + Sized>` is valid.

Imagine you have the following struct in addition to your code:

```rust
struct OtherBooksExtractor {}
impl Extractor for OtherBooksExtractor {
    fn parse(&self) -> String {
        "foobar".to_owned()
    }
}
```

Then you will expect that the following to work, based on just the types:

```rust
fn bla() -> Pass<OtherBookExtractor> {
   GutenbergRobot.get_pass()
}
assert_eq!(bla.extractor.parse(), "foobar")
```

However, you are constructing something more specific than the generic `Pass<E>` in your `get_pass`: a `Pass<BooksExtractor>`! If that would allow, that means that the code I wrote would not work as I might have expected.