# Can not assign a value to the field which has Iterator<Item=....> type

Tags: rust

The following code:

```rust
struct Abc<I>
    where I: Iterator<Item=u64> {

    my_iter: I,
}

impl<I> Abc<I>
    where I: Iterator<Item=u64> {

    fn func1(&mut self) {
        self.my_iter = vec![1,2,3,4,5].into_iter();
    }
}
```

fails to compile with the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/abc.rs:16:24
   |
12 | impl<I> Abc<I>
   |      - this type parameter
...
16 |         self.my_iter = vec![1,2,3,4,5].into_iter();
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `I`, found struct `std::vec::IntoIter`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `I`
                      found struct `std::vec::IntoIter<{integer}>`
```

Why it doesn't work and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why you declare Iterator<Item=u64>? In fact, u64 not implementing Iterator. Could you explain your idea?

Comment: @Zeppi `Item=u64` means the type of the element the iterator yields. The idea is very simple: a struct has a field of iterator type and at some point we want to assign that field with a concrete iterator.

Comment: You should use an associated type instead of a generic parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is it appropriate to use an associated type versus a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059370/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-an-associated-type-versus-a-generic-type)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in `Abc<I>` the *user* of `Abc` can choose any `I` as long as it implements `Iterator<Item = u64>`. But `Abc::func1()` assumes a very specific iterator. There are two ways to resolve it:

One is to make `func1()` only available if the iterator type is the one it can work with:

```
struct Abc<I> {
    my_iter: I,
}

impl Abc<std::vec::IntoIter<u64>> {
    fn func1(&mut self) {
        self.my_iter = vec![1,2,3,4,5].into_iter();
    }
}
```

The other is to give up on generics and use a trait object instead:

```
struct Abc {
    my_iter: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u64>>,
}

impl Abc {
    fn func1(&mut self) {
        self.my_iter = Box::new(vec![1,2,3,4,5].into_iter());
    }
}
```

Comment: Or to declare the struct as holding a `std::vec::IntoIter<u64>` in the first place if the OP doesn't need it to hold anything else.

Comment: @Jmb That would work too. I didn't consider that option because I found it unlikely that only that single iterator was ever needed in a generic function. But on the other hand, given that the OP is obviously a beginner, perhaps the use of generics was totally unintentional and arrived to using trial-and-error, in which case preserving it is a non-goal.

Answer (score 0):

The message of the compiler is correct, there is a type mismatch. You are trying to assign the value of type `std::vec::IntoIter<{integer}>` to a field with type `I`. You can see why this does not work with this example:

```
let mut val = Abc<MyCustomIteratorType<Item=u64>> { my_iter: MyCustomIteratorType::new() };
val.func1();
```

Here the call to `func1` will try to replace `my_iter` of type `MyCustomIteratorType` to `IntoIter`.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but one option to fix this issue is:

```
struct Abc<I>
    where I: Iterator<Item=u64> {

    my_iter: I,
}

impl Abc<std::vec::IntoIter<u64>>
    fn func1(&mut self) {
        self.my_iter = vec![1,2,3,4,5].into_iter();
    }
}
```

You can have different implementaions of `func1` for different iterator types.