# Elaborating on the "unicity" argument for the reason when to use associated types in Rust?

Tags: rust, types

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32065644/169992) to the question about *When is it appropriate to use an associated type versus a generic type?* gives a glimpse at the unicity argument:

> ```
> trait MyTrait {
>     type Return;
>     fn hello_world(&self) -> Self::Return;
> }
>
> trait MyTrait<Return> {
>     fn hello_world(&Self) -> Return;
> }
> ```
>
> - the first one enforces that for a given Self there is a single Return associated
> - the second one, instead, allows implementing MyTrait for Self for multiple Return

There are more complex examples of associated types [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html). And [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/14twron/comment/jr4o7lx/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) says:

> But it's really important that Iterator is "just one trait", since certain language constructs (notably for-loops) rely on it.
>
> Imagine you wrote for x in foo where foo implements `IntoIterator<i32>` and `IntoIterator<String>`. What would the type of `x` be?.

But I still am not following the exact reason this feature exists in Rust, and why it can't be avoided.

Can you elaborate further, with some examples / multiple cases to show why it is necessary and how the unicity argument comes into play? I am needing to wrap my head around this but still having trouble.

I couldn't explain how this works yet, even given all these comments.

Comment: Some people try to answer this, we still waiting for them... no seriously there is no simple answer to this, associate type "reduce" the possibility of "genericness", sometime it's good sometime it's not. Associate type allow the user to not always specify the concrete type whereas generic need to always be know. Also one way to put it is "is this generic type should be LINK to the trait ?" say otherwise does this generic is "own" by the trait. If you didn't understand it's normal as I said it's hard to explain.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we can find more official answer than from [the RFC that introduced associated types](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0195-associated-items.html), so I'll just cite it here:

> ## Motivation
>
> A typical example where associated items are helpful is data structures like
> graphs, which involve at least three types: nodes, edges, and the graph itself.
>
> In today's Rust, to capture graphs as a generic trait, you have to take the
> additional types associated with a graph as *parameters*:
>
> ```rust
> trait Graph<N, E> {
>     fn has_edge(&self, &N, &N) -> bool;
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> The fact that the node and edge types are parameters is confusing, since any
> concrete graph type is associated with a *unique* node and edge type. It is also
> inconvenient, because code working with generic graphs is likewise forced to
> parameterize, even when not all of the types are relevant:
>
> ```rust
> fn distance<N, E, G: Graph<N, E>>(graph: &G, start: &N, end: &N) -> uint { ... }
> ```
>
> With associated types, the graph trait can instead make clear that the node and
> edge types are determined by any `impl`:
>
> ```rust
> trait Graph {
>     type N;
>     type E;
>     fn has_edge(&self, &N, &N) -> bool;
> }
> ```
>
> and clients can abstract over them all at once, referring to them through the
> graph type:
>
> ```rust
> fn distance<G: Graph>(graph: &G, start: &G::N, end: &G::N) -> uint { ... }
> ```
>
> The following subsections expand on the above benefits of associated items, as
> well as some others.
>
> ### Associated types: engineering benefits for generics
>
> As the graph example above illustrates, associated *types* do not increase the
> expressiveness of traits *per se*, because you can always use extra type
> parameters to a trait instead. However, associated types provide several
> engineering benefits:
>
> - **Readability and scalability**
>
>   Associated types make it possible to abstract over a whole family of types at
>   once, without having to separately name each of them. This improves the
>   readability of generic code (like the `distance` function above).  It also
>   makes generics more "scalable": traits can incorporate additional associated
>   types without imposing an extra burden on clients that don't care about those
>   types.
>
>   In today's Rust, by contrast, adding additional generic parameters to a
>   trait often feels like a very "heavyweight" move.
> - **Ease of refactoring/evolution**
>
>   Because users of a trait do not have to separately parameterize over its
>   associated types, new associated types can be added without breaking all
>   existing client code.
>
>   In today's Rust, by contrast, associated types can only be added by adding
>   more type parameters to a trait, which breaks all code mentioning the trait.