# Mismatched type on generic function type with type alias

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm build a simple API and trying to implement clean architecture in Rust, I am using a trait to implement some sort of interface to abstract database implementation. In my in memory database impelentation I am using a type alias as returning type, but I am receiving this error: `` mismatched types expected type parameter `DB` found struct `Arc<tokio::sync::Mutex<Vec<_>>> ``

This is my trait:

```rust
pub trait IDatabase {
    fn connect<T>() -> T;
}
```

This is the in memory implementation:

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::sync::Mutex;
use crate::{infrastructure::data::interfaces::database::IDatabase, domain::entities::todo::Todo};

pub type DB = Arc<Mutex<Vec<Todo>>>;

pub struct InMemoryDB;

impl IDatabase for InMemoryDB {
    fn connect<DB>() -> DB {
        Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new())) // Error at this line
    }
}
```

Comment: `DB` is a new type parameter and the **caller** gets to decide it's type, it's not at all related to the type alias `DB` which gets shadowed.

Comment: Your `IDatabase` trait doesn't look like what you want, perhaps you wanted an associated type instead of a generic on `connect`?

Comment: Notice that the error hint `expected this type parameter` points exactly to ´DB` in `fn connect<DB>`; it's trying to tell you that `DB` as a return-type refers to the `DB` type-parameter introduced in `connect`; the identifier `DB` for the type-alias is effectively shadowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32059370/5397009

Comment: @kmdreko I want the trait to be generic and have the possibility to be implemented with different types of databases as return type, this would return an instance of the database connection.

Comment: You can still do that with an associated type. See [here on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d497339fc1bee09f19381fad5e018f9c). Different implementors can have different types returned for `connect`.