# Trait bounds with generic data type

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm trying to implement a basic trait called `Area` for planar geometric shapes such as a trapezium and a triangle. The code works when I fix the datatype to `f32`. But as soon as I try to convert this example to apply generic datatypes I run into trouble. Please consider the source code below:

```
pub trait Area<T> {
    fn calc_area(&self) -> T
    where
        T: std::ops::Add<Output = T>,
        T: std::ops::Div<Output = T>,
        T: From<f32>;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Triangle<T> {
    pub a: T,
    pub b: T,
    pub c: T,
    pub area: T,
    pub perimeter: T,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Trapezium<T> {
    pub a: T,
    pub b: T,
    pub h: T,
    pub area: T,
    pub perimeter: T,
}

impl<T> Area<T> for Trapezium<T> {
    fn calc_area(&self) -> T
    {
        return (self.a+self.b)/2.0.into()/self.h;
    }
}

fn main() {

    let mut t = Trapezium {a: 3.1, b: 6.9, h: 2.5, area: 0.0, perimeter: 0.0};
    t.area    = t.calc_area();
    println!("t: {:?}", t);
}
```

Compiling this code results in the following error:

```
Compiling geometric v0.1.0 (/Users/mabalenk/repo/git/rustup/src/geometric)
error[E0369]: cannot add `T` to `T`
  --> src/main.rs:46:23
   |
46 |         return (self.a+self.b)/2.0.into()/self.h;
   |                 ------^------ T
   |                 |
   |                 T
   |
help: consider restricting type parameter `T`
   |
43 | impl<T: std::ops::Add> Area<T> for Trapezium<T> {
   |       +++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0369`.
error: could not compile `geometric` (bin "geometric") due to previous error
```

My questions are:

1. I don't want to duplicate the bound information that I already specified in the trait definition. How do I do it correctly?
2. Why do I have to mention the generic datatype `<T>` after keywords `impl`, `Area` and `Trapezium`? What does it mean in each case? Maybe I'm overdoing it?

**UPDATE**

I modified my source code introducing a helper trait `Calculatable`. Please find my new version below:

```
pub trait Calculatable:
    std::ops::Add<Output = Self> +
    std::ops::Div<Output = Self> +
    std::ops::Mul<Output = Self> +
    From<f32>
{}

pub trait Area<T>
where
    T: Calculatable,
{
    fn calc_area(&self) -> T;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Triangle<T> {
    pub a: T,
    pub b: T,
    pub c: T,
    pub area: T,
    pub perimeter: T,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Trapezium<T> {
    pub a: T,
    pub b: T,
    pub h: T,
    pub area: T,
    pub perimeter: T,
}

impl<T> Area<T> for Trapezium<T>
where
    T: Calculatable,
{
    fn calc_area(&self) -> T
    {
        return (self.a+self.b)/2.0.into()*self.h;
    }
}

fn main() {

    let mut t = Trapezium {a: 3.1, b: 6.9, h: 2.5, area: 0.0, perimeter: 0.0};
    t.area    = t.calc_area();
    println!("t: {:?}", t);
}
```

However, I'm still unable to compile it. The compiler complains about unsatisfied bounds for `Trapezium<{float}>`:

```
Compiling geometric v0.1.0 (/Users/mabalenk/repo/git/rustup/src/geometric)
error[E0599]: the method `calc_area` exists for struct `Trapezium<{float}>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:62:19
   |
41 | pub struct Trapezium<T> {
   | -----------------------
   | |
   | method `calc_area` not found for this struct
   | doesn't satisfy `Trapezium<{float}>: Area<{float}>`
...
62 |     t.area    = t.calc_area();
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Trapezium<{float}>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
note: trait bound `{float}: Calculatable` was not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:51:8
   |
49 | impl<T> Area<T> for Trapezium<T>
   |         -------     ------------
50 | where
51 |     T: Calculatable,
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `geometric` (bin "geometric") due to previous error
```

It seems I need to add something else to the `Trapezium` definition or its `calc_area()` method.

Comment: `impl<T> Area<T> for Trapezium<T>` is a generic **implementation** of generic **trait** for generic **struct**. For example, you could avoid one like `impl<T> Area<T> for Trapezium<f32>`, or `impl<T> Area<f32> for Trapezium<T>`, or `impl Area<f32> for Trapezium<f32>`.

Answer (score 1):

1. That's not feasible here as Rust thinks there might possibilities that your struct/impl might want an extension to that trait bound (e.g: your `impl` might demand a `Copy` trait bound alongside whatever you need for the `Area` trait.
2. That comment by @chayim-friedman summarizes the answer. Basically the code that you wrote implies a big variety of types that it can accept. To add to it, you can even have `impl<T, U> Area<U> for Trapezium<T>`.

My suggestions are:

- Use [associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#specifying-placeholder-types-in-trait-definitions-with-associated-types) for the `Area` trait:

```rust
pub trait Area {
    // From @adesoji-alu's answer
    type Output: Calculatable;
    fn calc_area(&self) -> Self::Output;
}
```

There are a few [advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059370/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-an-associated-type-versus-a-generic-type) of doing this, but the major one is that you can't implement multiple return type for the same trait.

- Use the `num` crate. Instead of painstakingly defining `Mul`, `Div`, `Add`, etc. trait bounds, simply use the `Float` or `Integer` umbrella trait provided by `num` crate.
- Get rid of generic types all together. Simply use a constructor that accept any kind of number types (`usize`, `f32`, etc.), convert them to `f32` and store them as that. Similarly, methods should return the same number type. It might save you a lot of headache later when you want to implement other functions (e.g: what if you have to find out if a shape will fit in another shape? If those two have different types, you have to convert them into a common one first)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the `num` crate. I will use it in the future. I agree to bringing everything to one datatype under the hood. But this is supposed to be a simple example of using traits with generics.