How to implement Rust generics with traits?
I'm very new to Rust and as a project to both learn some Rust and brush up on some simple data processing concepts wanted to build a preprocessing library for matrices. I setup some basic preprocessor traits representing the fitter and the actual transformer:
// Trait for a preprocessor.
pub trait Preprocessor<I, O = I> {

    /// Function to scale the data. 
    fn transform(&mut self, intputs: I) -> Result<O>;

}

/// Trait for the preprocessor fitters.
pub trait PreprocessorFitter<I, O: Preprocessor<I>> {

    /// Fit the preprocessor to the dataset.
    fn fit(self, inputs: &I) -> Result<O>;

    /// Get the fit status for the preprocessor fitter.
    fn fit_status(&self) -> FitStatus;

}

/// Enum for the fit status.
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub enum FitStatus {
    /// The fitter has not been fit.
    NotFit,
    /// The fitter has been fit.
    Fit
}

The Preprocessor trait can handle two generics because sometimes, such as for a label encoder, we'll be transforming between different types. However, for other preprocessors, such as a scaler, the input and output types will be the same.
Here is my attempt at the label encoder:
/// Struct for the Label Encoder.
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct LabelEncoder<K, V>
where
    K: Clone + Debug,
    V: Float + Clone + Debug,
{
    /// The fitter.
    fitter: LabelEncoderFitter<K, V>,
}

impl<K, V> Preprocessor<Vector<K>, Vector<V>> for LabelEncoder<K, V> 
where 
    K: Clone + Debug + Eq + Hash,
    V: Float + Clone + Debug,
{
    /// Transforms the Vector based on the fitted Label Encoder hash map.
    fn transform(&mut self, inputs: Vector<K>) -> Result<Vector<V>, Error> {
        let mut mapped_vec = Vec::with_capacity(inputs.size());
        for element in inputs {
            let mapped_value = self.fitter.label_map.get(&element);
            match mapped_value {
                Some(v) => mapped_vec.push(*v),
                None => return Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidState, "Label not found in encoder, invalid fitter state.")),
            }
        }
        Ok(Vector::new(mapped_vec))
    }

}

/// Struct for the Label Encoder fitter.
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct LabelEncoderFitter<K, V>
where
    K: Clone + Debug,
    V: Float + Clone + Debug,
{
    /// The label map.
    label_map: HashMap<K, V>,
    /// Indicates whether the fitter has been fit.
    fit: FitStatus,
}

impl<K, V> Default for LabelEncoderFitter<K, V>
where
    K: Clone + Debug,
    V: Float + Clone + Debug,
{
    /// Creates an inital, default Label Encoder fitter.
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            label_map: HashMap::default(),
            fit: FitStatus::default(),
        }
    }
}

impl<K, V> PreprocessorFitter<Vector<K>, LabelEncoder<K, V>> for LabelEncoderFitter<K, V>
where
    K: Clone + Debug + Eq + Hash,
    V: Float + Clone + Debug,
{
    /// Fits the label encoder fitter on the given vector.
    fn fit(mut self, inputs: &Vector<K>) -> Result<LabelEncoder<K, V>, Error> {
        self.label_map.clear();
        let mut encoder_value: V = V::zero();

        for input in inputs {
            if !self.label_map.contains_key(input) {
                self.label_map.insert(input.clone(), encoder_value);
                encoder_value = encoder_value + V::one();
            }
        }
        self.fit = FitStatus::Fit;
        Ok(LabelEncoder { fitter: self })
    }

    /// Get the fit status for the preprocessor fitter.
    fn fit_status(&self) -> FitStatus {
        self.fit
    }
}

I continue to get this compile error:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `LabelEncoder<K, V>: Preprocessor<Vector<K>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/preprocessing/encoders/labelencoder.rs:80:12
   |
80 | impl<K, V> PreprocessorFitter<Vector<K>, LabelEncoder<K, V>> for LabelEncoderFitter<K, V>
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Preprocessor<Vector<K>>` is not implemented for `LabelEncoder<K, V>`
   |

I'm struggling to understand how to fix this. From my understanding, my impl block for the PreprocessorFitter is taking a Vector as the I and the O is getting set to a generic that has to satisfy the trait bound Preprocessor<I>, which in this case is Preprocessor<Vector<K>>. Since my impl block for the Preprocessor defines two generics, K and V, then this is seen as a different case, therefore the trait bound is not satisfied. This is my very loose understanding of what is happening. I have a feeling I have to adjust my PreprocessorFitter trait to also take multiple generics and one with a default value like I did with the Preprocessor trait but I'm getting rather lost on how to fix this. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

PreprocessorFitter requires that its second type parameter implement Preprocessor<I> which (due to the default of Preprocessor's second parameter) is shorthand for Preprocessor<I, I> where I is its first type parameter.  Your failing implementation therefore requires LabelEncoder<K, V> to implement Preprocessor<Vector<K>, Vector<K>> whereas it only implements Preprocessor<Vector<K>, Vector<V>>.  I haven't tried to understand your code beyond that to suggest what the right way to fix this might be, but hopefully that will set you on the right track?

Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059370/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-an-associated-type-versus-a-generic-type?

If you are happy for the failing implementation to be restricted to cases where K = V you could need only make it generic over one parameter, ie impl<K> PreprocessorFitter<Vector<K>> for LabelEncoder<K, K>.  Otherwise perhaps you want to add a third type parameter to PreprocessorFitter?  Again, I haven't really tried to understand the logic here just speaking from a cursory glance at the types.

In your case, I think I should remain a type parameter, but O should probably be an associated type.
